# Как складывать вероятности?

Tags: математика, теория-вероятностей

Допустим я заболел гриппом, и купил себе 2 разных лекарства производители которых утверждают что шанс исцелиться от гриппа принимая их лекарства 50%. У одного 50% и у другого тоже 50% С какой вероятностью я выздоровею если буду принимать оба?

Comment: Вам [сюда](http://math.hashcode.ru/)

Comment: 75% - не болейте!

Comment: Математика в целом и теорвер в частности не входят в тематику SO на русском. Здесь только программирование, администрирование и смежные области.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видите ли, тут играют роль *условные вероятности*, потому как лекарства между собой взаимодействуют, так что все может получиться как с тем жаропонижающим:
- прием одного грамма снижает температуру на градус...
- профессор, значит, приняв 20 грамм, можно снизить температуру до комнатной?
- вообще-то да, но тут уже механизм несколько иной...

А вот если бросить две монетки и ждать, не выпадет ли хотя бы один орел, то тут проще считать вероятность, что **не** выпадет ни один - т.е. не выпадет на первой (50%) **И** не выпадет на второй (50%) - а для **И** независимые вероятности просто перемножаются. Так что вероятность, что не выпадет ни один орел - 0.5*0.5 = 0.25, а тогда вероятность, что выпадет хотя бы один - 1-0.25=0.75=75%.